# non-blocking write of large object with netty

Tags: netty

In reference to my earlier question [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1903), I am trying to figure out the correct way to stream a large object from the server to the client.

The server is doing a `write` followed by a `flush`, and there's a handler in the `Channel` which will take the large object and iteratively decompose it into small chunks doing a `writeAndFlush` on each chunk.  I was hoping this would turn the large object into a stream of manageable messages the client could consume and reconstruct as needed.

What I see is each of those sits in the outbound buffer until either they've all be written and can be sent, or I OOM the server.  I'd like them to get flushed/sent as they're written to avoid this issue.  (If I don't OOM the server, it does come into the client as a stream like designed, it's that the transmission of any data is blocked until *all* data is written).

If I try to do the decompose operation by dispatching it via `Callable` to the `Executor` associated with the `ChannelHandlerContext` and then marking the original `ChannelPromise` as successful, I still see the same behavior.

If I instead use a non-netty `Executor`, I seem to get the correct behavior, I can see data landing on the client immediately, but this feels like the wrong solution.

When decomposing the large object into smaller, writable ones, I do see that immediately after I write the first object, the channel writeability changes to false.  I realize, as @norman-maurer pointed out, that I should stop writing at this point.  But it's not clear how to get the event that I can safely resume writing.  It's also not clear how you'd handle the write in that case, but maybe that is because I don't see how you can get the event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Norman did answer this but I'll try and make it a bit clearer.

It sounds like your first attempt is looping something like this

```
while(moreToSend) {
    channel.writeAndFlush(...)
    moreToSend = checkFinished();
}
```

It sounds like you're doing this in the channel's IO thread which is the thread which will write your data to the socket. The thread may not be able to write the data while it's processing the loop. Netty's only option is to queue the writes.

I'm not completely familiar with Netty 4.x (still on 3.x) however it sounds like the same thing is happening in your second attempt. By dispatching the Callable to the executor associated with the `ChannelHandlerContext` then, unless you've wrapped you handler in another executor, you're actually asking the Callable to be executed on the IO thread and the same problem applies.

Norman is saying that you should call `writeAndFlush` until `channel.isWritable` returns false. You can resume writing when Netty raises `channelWritabilityChanged` and `channel.isWritable` returns true. Note `channelWritabilityChanged` is raised on `ChannelInboundHandler` which implies that your handler needs to be both `ChannelInboundHandler` and `ChannelOutboundHandler` (assuming it's already an outbound handler).

Alternatively, rather than trying to write as much as possible in one go, you can write the first chunk and register a listener with the returned `ChannelFuture`. When `operationComplete` is called back, then if `future.isSuccess` returns true write the next chunk in the same way. This way you will write chunks as and when the previous chunk has been flushed to the OS send buffers. It should also work well if you need to mix sending the large object with other traffic.

Comment: Writability events seem to only be dispatched on inbound handlers (ie `ChannelInboundHandler`); so it's not straightforward to get that event on an outbound handler which is doing the write.  I guess I could make it also an inbound handler to get that event, but that seems wrong.  I am able to cascade writes via a series of cascaded `ChannelPromise` events, which works, but feels similarly kludgy

Comment: To wrap up, extending the duplex handler to get writability events and toggling the stream on and off in synch with those write events resolves the issue.